# Find number of solutions of $x_1 \wedge x_2 \oplus x_2 \wedge x_3 \oplus ... \oplus x_{n-1} \wedge x_n = 1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to find number of solutions of boolean equation $$x_1 \wedge x_2 \oplus x_2 \wedge x_3 \oplus ... \oplus x_{n-1} \wedge x_n = 1$$
where $\oplus$ is [Exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) and $\wedge$ is [Logical conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)
My knowledge of combinatorics is not good enough, so my first idea was to code a program which produces correct output for further investigation.

And the output was something like this

```
n = 2   counter: 1
n = 3   counter: 2
n = 4   counter: 6
n = 5   counter: 12
n = 6   counter: 28
n = 7   counter: 56
n = 8   counter: 120
n = 9   counter: 240
n = 10  counter: 496
n = 11  counter: 992
n = 12  counter: 2016
n = 13  counter: 4032
n = 14  counter: 8128
n = 15  counter: 16256
n = 16  counter: 32640
n = 17  counter: 65280
n = 18  counter: 130816
n = 19  counter: 261632
n = 20  counter: 523776
```

After some googling, I came out with [this](https://oeis.org/A032085) sequence
I'm really interested about how can I solve this problem by some "counting" methods. [Here's](http://pastebin.com/DGrmeRaS) the program I wrote in case you're interested about the output (hope it is correct).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does $\oplus$ mean in this context?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk it means exclusive or here.

Comment: fixed $x_1 x_2$ part too, really sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the generalized $\bigoplus$ is true iff an odd number of terms are true, and since the terms are all of the form $x_i \land x_{i+1}$, meaning that the only true terms are of the form $1 \land 1$, here is something you can do to find the numbers in your series much more quickly (that is: without checking every possible bitstring):

Let $a_{11}^n$ be the number of solutions for $n$ where $x_n = 1$

Let $a_{10}^n$ be the number of solutions for $n$ where $x_n = 0$

Let $a_{01}^n$ be the number of non-solutions for $n$ where $x_n = 1$

Let $a_{00}^n$ be the number of non-solutions for $n$ where $x_n = 0$

You can now easily find the terms $a_{ij}^{n+1}$ on the basis of the terms $a_{ij}^{n}$.

For example, to figure out $a_{11}^{n+1}$: There are two ways you can get these:

You can add a 1 to the previous non-solutions that end with a 1, thus adding the term $1 \land 1$ at the end, thus going from an even to an odd number of terms that are true, and thus turning the non-solution to a solution.

Or you can add a 1 to the previous solutions that end with a 0, thus adding the term $0 \land 1$ at the end, thus keeping an odd number of terms that are true, and thus keeping it a solution.

Thus:

$a_{11}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{10}^n$

Likewise, you can find:

$a_{10}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{10}^n$

$a_{01}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{00}^n$

$a_{00}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{00}^n$

Now, this doesn't give you a nice formula yet, but at least you can generate your numbers real fast (since for any $n$, it is $a_{11}^n + a_{10}^n$), starting with:

$a_{11}^2 = 1$ (11 is only solution ending with 1)

$a_{10}^2 = 0$ (no solutions end with 0)

$a_{01}^2 = 1$ (01 is only non-solution ending with 1)

$a_{00}^2 = 2$ (00 and 10 are both non-solutions ending with 0)

So you get as successive numbers:

$a_{11} : 1,1,4,6,16,...$

$a_{10} : 0,1,2,6,12,...$

$a_{01} : 1,3,4,10,16,...$

$a_{00} : 2,3,6,10,20,...$

And thus your series (again, add $a_{11}^n$ to $a_{10}^n$): 1,2,6,12,28,...

And someone who is better at math than I am can probably turn this into some kind of matrix operation, and figure out a quick formula.

**ADDITION**

I created the multiplication matrix, observed its behavior by multiplying it by itself, and was able to generate the following hypothesis:

CLAIM: for any $n \geq 2$:

$a_{11}^n = \begin{cases} 2^{2k} &\mbox{if } n = 2k+2 \\
2^{2k+1}-2^k & \mbox{if } n =2k+3 \end{cases}$

$a_{10}^n = \begin{cases} 2^{2k}-2^k &\mbox{if } n = 2k+2 \\
2^{2k+1}-2^k & \mbox{if } n =2k+3 \end{cases}$

$a_{01}^n = \begin{cases} 2^{2k} &\mbox{if } n = 2k+2 \\
2^{2k+1}+2^k & \mbox{if } n =2k+3 \end{cases}$

$a_{00}^n = \begin{cases} 2^{2k}+2^k &\mbox{if } n = 2k+2 \\
2^{2k+1}+2^k & \mbox{if } n =2k+3 \end{cases}$

Proof of Claim by Induction:

Base: n=2, i.e. n = 2*k+2 for k=0

$a_{11}^n = 2^{2k} = 2^{2*0} = 2^0 = 1$

$a_{10}^n = 2^{2k}-2^k = 2^{2*0}-2^0 = 2^0-1 = 1-1=0$

$a_{01}^n = 2^{2k} = 2^{2*0} = 2^0 = 1$

$a_{00}^n = 2^{2k}+2^k = 2^{2*0}+2^0 = 2^0+1 = 1+1=2$

All these values are correct as shown above.

Step: We need to consider two cases:

Case 1: $n=2k+2$

By Inductive Hypothesis, we can assume:

$a_{11}^n = 2^{2k}$

$a_{10}^n = 2^{2k}-2^k$

$a_{01}^n = 2^{2k}$

$a_{00}^n = 2^{2k}+2^k$

Now let's consider $n+1 = 2k+3$:

$a_{11}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{10}^n = 2^{2k} + 2^{2k}-2^k = 2^{2k+1}-2^k$

$a_{10}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{10}^n = 2^{2k} + 2^{2k}-2^k = 2^{2k+1}-2^k$

$a_{01}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{00}^n = 2^{2k} + 2^{2k}+2^k = 2^{2k+1}+2^k$

$a_{00}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{00}^n = 2^{2k} + 2^{2k}+2^k = 2^{2k+1}+2^k$

These are all what they should be in accordance with the Claim.

Case 2: $n=2k+3$

By Inductive Hypothesis, we can assume:

$a_{11}^n = 2^{2k+1}-2^k$

$a_{10}^n = 2^{2k+1}-2^k$

$a_{01}^n = 2^{2k+1}+2^k$

$a_{00}^n = 2^{2k+1}+2^k$

Now let's consider $n+1 = 2k+4 = 2(k+1) + 2$:

$a_{11}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{10}^n = 2^{2k+1}+2^k + 2^{2k+1}-2^k = 2^{2k+2} = 2^{2(k+1)}$

$a_{10}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{10}^n = 2^{2k+1}-2^k + 2^{2k+1}-2^k = 2^{2k+2}-2^{k+1} = 2^{2(k+1)}-2^{k+1}$

$a_{01}^{n+1} = a_{11}^n + a_{00}^n = 2^{2k+1}-2^k + 2^{2k+1}+2^k = 2^{2k+2} = 2^{2(k+1)}$

$a_{00}^{n+1} = a_{01}^n + a_{00}^n = 2^{2k+1}+2^k + 2^{2k+1}+2^k = 2^{2k+2}+2^{k+1} = 2^{2(k+1)}+2^{k+1}$

Again, these are all what they should be in accordance with the Claim.

Hence, by induction, the Claim is proven.

Finally then, where $n$ is the number of variables $x_i$, we have that the number of solutions is:

$f(n) = a_{11}^n + a_{10}^n = \begin{cases} 2^{2k} + 2^{2k} - 2^k = 2^{2k+1} - 2^k &\mbox{if } n = 2k+2 \\
2^{2k+1} - 2^k + 2^{2k+1} - 2^k = 2^{2k+2} - 2^{k+1} & \mbox{if } n =2k+3 \end{cases}$

Quick check:

$f(2) = 2^1-2^0 = 2-1 = 1$

$f(3) = 2^2-2^1 = 4-2 = 2$

$f(4) = 2^3-2^1 = 8-2 = 6$

$f(5) = 2^4-2^2 = 16-4 = 12$

$f(6) = 2^5 - 2^2 = 32-4=28$

...looks right!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I'm truly excited in this approach. Just 2 questions. The place where $a_{00}^2 = 2$, shouldn't this be just 0? and am I right, that your index $i$ gives information whether previous case was a solution or not, and index $j$ tells us about last variable?

Comment: @shcolf Glad it is of use!  And yes, that's how I meant the  $i$ and $j$, though the $i$ not about the previous case, but current case.  E.g. $a_{10}^3$ is the number of strings of length 3 that are solutions whose last digit is a $0$. But $a_{00}^n$ really is 2, since both 00 and 10 are non-solutions and end with a 0.

Comment: @shcolf  I figured out the formula! Formula and its proof are now provided in the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

For each assignment of values to $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ we get in induced subgraph of the path graph $P(n)$ on vertices $1,\ldots,n$: specifically, we get the subgraph that has an edge $\{k,k+1\}$ iff $x_k\land x_{k+1}=1$. Then $\bigoplus_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_k\land x_{k+1})=1$ iff the corresponding induced subgraph has an odd number of edges. In view of the COMMENTS section of [OEIS A032085](https://oeis.org/A032085), this shows that we really are dealing with that sequence. Thus, if $a_n$ is the number of solutions for $n$ variables, the sequence satisfies the recurrence

$$a_n=6a_{n-2}-8a_{n-4}$$

for $n\ge 6$ with $a_2=1,a_3=2,a_4=6$, and $a_5=12$.

This is really just two interlaced instances of the recurrence $b_n=6b_{n-1}-8b_{n-2}$, one with initial values $b_1=1$ and $b_2=6$, and the other with initial values $b_1=2$ and $b_2=12$. The auxiliary equation for this recurrence is $x^2-6x+8=0$, with zeroes $2$ and $4$, and it’s easy to check that the initial values $b_1=2$ and $b_2=12$ yield the solution $b_n=4^n-2^n$. The initial values $b_1=1$ and $b_2=6$, being half as large, must then yield the solution

$$b_n=\frac12\left(4^n-2^n\right)=2^{n-1}\left(2^n-1\right)\;.$$

In terms of the original sequence we have

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
a_{2k}&=2^{k-1}(2^k-1)=2^{2k-1}-2^{k-1}\\
a_{2k+1}&=4^k-2^k\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

These can be combined as

$$a_n=2^{n-1}-2^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor}\;.$$